# Error ao criar um CRUD em ASP.NET Core MVC com Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Sou nova em programação e estou criando um CRUD em ASP.NET Core MVC com Entity Framework, banco de dados SQL Server, através de um tutorial na Internet, baixei os bendito pacotes do nugets,que são:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

Depois que criei o `controller`, fui testar para ver se aparecia os dados(CRUD) no site porém não aparece nada, por gentileza, alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CRUDProdutosASPNETCoreMVC.Models
{
    public class Produto
    {
        [Key]
        public int Produto_id { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
        public int Quantidade { get; set; }
        public decimal Preco { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

```
using CRUDProdutosASPNETCoreMVC.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CRUDProdutosASPNETCoreMVC.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Produto> Produto { get; set; }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder
                .UseSqlServer(@"Server=DESKTOP-DJRCE3V;Database=DBAppSample;Integrated Security=True");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A conexão com esse server "DESKTOP-DJRCE3V" está correta, consegue acessar ?

Comment: Eu creio que sim,porquê no campo de nome de servidor quando abre o sql server, aparece este nome e também para confirmar, eu entrei na propriedade do sql server e parece este DESKTOP-DJRCE3V como nome de servidor,agora nome de string de conexão é outroDESKTOP-DJRCE3V\Diana, tentei tbm mas o erro persiste.

Comment: Olá! Semente com essas informações é impossível saber, somente por chute e adivinhação.

Comment: Ok... A imagem tem um pouco mais de informação. Adiciona o seu startup.cs à pergunta, pf.

Comment: Qual é o erro???

Comment: @DianaMoura, você gerou e executou as migrations ?

Comment: @Matheus esse migrations que vc cita é para lidar com alterações de modelo usando migrações do Code First para alterar o esquema de banco de dados em vez de descartar e recriar o banco de dados? ser a resposta for sim, não criei. Vou tentar aqui criar.

Comment: @Matheus criei as migrations e continua com o mesmo problema. quando clico no IIS Express, abre a página, Esta página localhost não foi encontrada Nenhuma página da Web foi encontrada para o endereço Web: https://localhost:44355/Student/Privacy
HTTP ERROR 404

Comment: @DianaMoura, este erro acontece se a página não existe, veja dentro de Views se existe uma pasta e arquivo .cshtml da pagina

Comment: @Harry Existe em views a pasta com nome da classe de modelo, e também na views tem  na pasta shared tem viewimporta.cshtml  e também dentro de shared tem layout.cshtml

Comment: @Harry eu deletei o projeto que postei o codigo e a foto aqui no site,e fiz outro seguindo o tutorial da microsoft para ver se eu fiz algum passo errado ou se tinha algum pacote para instalar, mas nesse novo projeto também quando clico no IIExpress e quando clico no nome do student para mostra nomes dos estudante aparece este erro Esta página localhost não foi encontradaNenhuma página da Web foi encontrada para o endereço Web: https://localhost:44355/Student/Privacy
HTTP ERROR 404

Comment: @novic quando executo o site  e clico no nome do projeto para para parecer o nomes do alunos aparece esta informação. "Esta página localhost não foi encontradaNenhuma página da Web foi encontrada para o endereço Web: https://localhost:44355/Student/Privacy
HTTP ERROR 404"

Comment: @tvdias desculpa a pergunta, como faço isto?

Comment: @Harry eu consegui resolver o problema,eu coloquei no nome do servidor do sql correto,e no Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml no <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Students" asp-action="Index">Students</a> Students estava sem a consoante S no final, coloquei igual a pasta Students e funcionou, clico lá no site em Students e aparece as informações, e testei delete,creat, e deu tudo certo.Obrigada harry

Comment: @tvdias Consegui resolver, mais mesmo assim obrigada. :)

Comment: @novic consegui resolver, era o servifor que estava com nome diferente, depois e no Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml no <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Students" asp-action="Index">Students</a> Students estava sem a consoante S no final, coloquei igual a pasta Students e funcionou, clico lá no site em Students e aparece as informações, e testei delete,creat, e deu tudo certo, Obrigada. :)